# Need to optimize code (Reduce the size) CODESYS ST (TwinCat 2) to save memory

Tags: twincat, codesys, st

The code size (CODESYS ST, TwinCat 2) for the beckhoff BC9000 PLC (64 kB max) should be reduced to a minimum:

`var`

`word_CO2: word;`

(*code skipped*)

Need to reduce the size of this code:

`MEMCPY(ADR(word_CO2),ADR(ReceiveBuffer[3]),1);`

`MEMCPY(ADR(word_CO2)+1,ADR(ReceiveBuffer[2]),1);`

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: Reduce the size of this code : "MEMCPY(ADR(word_CO2),ADR(ReceiveBuffer[3]),1);

MEMCPY(ADR(word_CO2)+1,ADR(ReceiveBuffer[2]),1);"

Comment: So do I understand this correctly? You are trying to download your program on you PLC, but you're running out of memory? If so, does it happen while you are trying to download the program onto the PLC, or while running the program at runtime?

Comment: I can compile the code successfully when it is less than 64kb in size. I need to increase the code, but I get 64kb limit. In my code there are a lot of MEMCPY() commands, when I get a number (INT / WORD) from 2 array elements. If I can optimize these lines I can rewrite the code and get a few more KBs for the new code.

Comment: I do not think MEMCPY is connected to your error. Why do you think it is this part of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce code size in CoDeSys 2.3 do the following:

1. Go into 'Project' -> 'Options' -> 'Build'.
2. Select 'Replace constants'.
3. Select 'Exclude objects'... and start excluding grayout FBs and FUNs in the system libraries one-by-one.
4. Perform 'Clean All' and 'Rebuild All' commands if you are not sure in what you are excluding. Also perform them regulary in between.

If the above does not help your code needs review and optimization. Generally speaking try to avoid multiple IF...ELSIF statemenets, use MUX and SEL operators instead and (a little bit of) CASE logic. Switching to POINTER arithmetic and compacting data into ARRAYS also helps. Use bit access to BYTE, WORD and DWORD variables instead of BOOL variables.

Comment: Good ideas! And also, use `VAR_IN_OUT` everywhere if possible (functions, function blocks etc). In that way, no new variables are allocated.

Comment: @Quirzo, Don't POINTERs also take space? POINTERs are stored as `__XWORD` (4 Bytes on a 32bit PLC, and 8 Bytes on a 64bitPLC), or am I wrong?

Comment: That's right. So there is no use for using pointer instead of INT etc. However if you have strings or structs, you can save space by using pointers, references and IN_OUTs.

Comment: @Quirzo, True, and that's why I wouldn't use POINTERS/REFERENCE _everywhere_, but mainly with structures. Also, `Function Blocks` use a lot of space (both code an memory), so I'd avoid them in favor of structures and functions.

Answer (score 1):

MEMCPY is already an optimized library function (I.e. it calls a function, it shouldn’t “inline code”).  I don’t see how you are going to optimize that anymore than it is.  Your code either needs some restructuring to reduce repetitive code in other places, reduce the number of memory variables you are using  or a better piece of hardware. 64 kB is pretty small nowadays. The PLCopen controllers I am involved with have 4 MB with 64 kB for just the retain data...

Perhaps rework your question as you have seen in the comments, readers are really not quite clear why you have assumed MEMCPY is your troublemaker....